The user profile value is shown Nill in power app,why?
If(IsBlank(Office365Users.UserProfile(Parent.Default).DisplayName),"Nil",Office365Users.UserProfile(Parent.Default).DisplayName)  This is the error in power app which shows the user profile value is nill  why this error come and how to resolve it.
I Dont understand exactly where we get the data of office 365 user in power app
and i want total step by step solution of this error
